# Echo image in wordpress php with SQL variable

Tags: php, mysql

For the life of me I can't find why this line doesn't output an image in a table.

```
echo "<td>" . "<img src=/images/helmets/" . $row["Flag1"] . ".png>" . "</td>"
```

I'm sure it's a " issue.

I know that the sql output is correct because echo $row["Flag1"] give the correct result but I can't get it to display a png with the same name.

I am using "Allow PHP" in wordpress

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: Well whats the rendered HTML?

Answer (score 2):

`src` needs to have its value  between '' or "". You can try this

```
echo "<td>" . "<img src='/images/helmets/" . $row["Flag1"] . ".png'>" . "</td>"
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `$row['Flag1']` has a valid value, try this

```
echo "<td><img src=\"/images/helmets/{$row['Flag1']}.png\"></td>";
```

Comment: embedding an array element inside a string gives unusual results.  I wouldn't do it

Comment: Well after you edited it to include the {} then it works.  The way you originally posted was unreliable

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, these all worked including mine when I realized that a capital letter on the file name made a difference and changed it.